# Sorting Dictionary by value of key within a key

Tags: python-3.x

I want to sort a dictionary by descending order by a value of a key within a key.
In my sample, I want to sort by little 'c'

Here is what I looks like now:

```
sample = {'A': {'a':22, 'b':24, 'c':80},
 'B': {'a':12, 'b':13, 'c':55},
 'C': {'a':44, 'b':33, 'c':99}
}
```

and here is my desired output:

```
sample = {'C': {'a':44, 'b':33, 'c':99},
 'A': {'a':22, 'b':24, 'c':80},
 'B': {'a':12, 'b':13, 'c':55}
}
```

I tried this bit of code by clearly its not right:

```
newdict = {}
for key, value in sorted(sample.items(), key=lambda item: item['c'], reverse=True):
     newdict[key] = value
sample = newdict
```

Thank you all for the help in solving this little puzzle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, the key function should be:

```
key=lambda item: item[1]['c']
```

Rewritten to be more Pythonic:

```
sample = dict(sorted(sample.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['c'], reverse=True))
```

(The `dict` constructor can take an iterable of item tuples)

Comment: you sir, are brilliant